# "only instance methods can be declared @ibaction" error

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction

This is the problem:

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
```

I keep receiving "only instance methods can be declared @ibaction" error. Help me fix this. Please don't suggest to remove "@IBAction". Thank you. This is the whole messed up coding situation:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var userUid: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }
    func goToFeedVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? userVC {
                if userUid != nil {
                    destination.userUid = userUid
            }
                if emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
                { (user,error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if user != nil {
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                        self.goToFeedVC()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.goToCreateUserVC()
                }
            });
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common beginner mistake caused by messy formatting. Your indentation changes from method to method, you are not careful with placing your opening and closing bracers to the correctly indented places and that makes you miss that your code structure is wrong.

Let's see your code with consistent indentation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var userUid: String!

    func goToCreateUserVC() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }
    func goToFeedVC() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? userVC {
                if userUid != nil {
                    destination.userUid = userUid
                }
                if emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
            }
        }
        @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user,error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if user != nil {
                            self.goToCreateUserVC()
                            self.goToFeedVC()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's obvious that your `signInTapped` is actually defined inside `prepare` and therefore it's not an instance method but an inner function.

This is easy to fix by moving the closing bracers to correct places:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var userUid: String!

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }
    func goToFeedVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? userVC {
                if userUid != nil {
                    destination.userUid = userUid
                }
                if emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user,error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if user != nil {
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                        self.goToFeedVC()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.goToCreateUserVC()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To increase code readability (which is the real problem here), we also use to reduce the number of indendation levels, for example, using *early returns*:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var userUid: String!

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }
    func goToFeedVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard
            segue.identifier == "SignUp",
            let destination = segue.destination as? userVC
        else {
            return
        }

        if userUid != nil {
            destination.userUid = userUid
        }
        if emailField.text != nil {
            destination.emailField = emailField.text
        }
        if passwordField.text != nil {
            destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text else {
            return
        }

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user,error) in
            if error == nil {
                if user != nil {
                    self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    self.goToFeedVC()
                }
            } else {
                self.goToCreateUserVC()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! @Sulthan. There is no error showing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Then make the method an instance method (by declaring it outside of any method in that object) and simply call it from anywhere in the view controller. An instance method or property is a method or property that is available to the entire instance of that object. Declaring your method inside `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` makes it available only to that method.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
                { (user,error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if user != nil {
                            self.goToCreateUserVC()
                            self.goToFeedVC()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    }
            });
        }
    }

    var userUid: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }
    func goToFeedVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? userVC {
                if userUid != nil {
                    destination.userUid = userUid
                }
                if emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
            }
        }
        signInTapped(sender)
    }
}
```